# How to view the localhost of another computer in the same network?

Tags: share

We have a team, working on a website. And I am planning to keep the files in one computer and let the guys access the files and folders, edit it, test it, view it in browser.

I am using WAMP Server. And I want it's localhost to be available from other computers.

How to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

quoting and answering your questions:

**> "...I want it's localhost to be available from other computers"**

Sorry, but "localhost" (meaning "this computer") is the standard hostname given to the address of the loopback network
interface. The name is also a reserved domain name, so you can't make computer's localhost to be avalible from other
computers.

**> "...I am planning to keep the files in one computer and let the guys access the files
and folders, edit it, test it, view it in browser"**

To start with, you need some kind of FTP server software, to provide access/edit files capability for your team.
I think [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) should fit your needs.

Second, ensure other computer in your network can "see" the machine WAMP running on. Go "Start" -> "Run", type "cmd" there
and press enter. In text console appeared type:

```
C:\Documents and Settings>ipconfig
Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydomain.com
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.221.235
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.221.1
```

This is your WAMP machine IP address. try to ping it from another box in your network(e.g. "Start" -> "Run", type "cmd",
In text console appeared type: `ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - IP address in your case.). If it pings as
well you can proceed with next steps, if not - check your network/firewall settings configured as well.

The next one, Apache server configuration. Ensure Apache is configured to bind/listen to your xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx network
interface(if it configured to "localhost" it is reachable only for machihe it is running on).

Try run `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80` on WAMP machine, if you can see answer from Apache web server than it configuration
is correct. Try the same from another PC in your network - you should get the same response from Apache.

If you can ping and connect by telnet to your WAMP machine from another, then try access it in browser by typing
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/

After this you can proceed with FTP server configuring and share your work. You can either use classic windows
file sharing.

In your case(developers team) recommended to use [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) for code versioning.

Comment: This is a very good explanation.

Comment: No it is not. It is possible to access what runs on port 8080 from another computer of the network

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can just access the website from another computer as http://servername.domain/

If you cannot, then you'll have to troubleshoot. Probable problems:

- firewall on server prevents access
- Apache is configured to only bind/listen to localhost (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html)

Comment: http://servername.domain is not working and firewall is not blocking it.

Comment: Then you'll have to start your standard networking troubleshootin process (can the computers see each other? is the routing correct? can they ping each other? see open ports? etc.). If you cannot do this, then get the help of someone competend with networking. Without basic networking knowledge, this will be very hard to fix.

Comment: @Starx ok, I do a very stupid question, please don't be offended, you did not try http://servername.domain/ *literally*, right? Try with the IP address of that computer

Comment: I managed to access the website, but now I can't access phpmyadmin anyidea. @mangetic_dud, I did try with the IP also but.........nothing

Answer (score 0):

Forward gives you a shareable URL that works inside a network and over the internet. It's easy to setup and works great for development check it out: https://forwardhq.com

Probably not the best choice if you just want access internally, but still a good tool to have in your toolbox.

Disclaimer: I work on Forward.

Answer (score -2):

It is very simple you will have to modify httpd.conf file in wamp apache module

go through this

http://www.ddcantt.in/2014/08/how-to-share-wamp-localhost-in-lan.html

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  Link-only answers are discouraged here, because your answer becomes useless if the link goes away.  Instead, please describe the solution here.